# Can I continue playing Magic 2015 on other device or platform?

Tags: android, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers, google-play-games, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2015

I started playing Magic 2015 for Android on my smartphone. Now I installed the same app on my Android tablet also and used the same Google Play account for login.

Somehow I anticipated to be able to continue playing where I left off on my phone. I was wrong, I had to start from scratch again.

Is there any way I can achieve this - to continue playing cross-device - or is this just completely separate? If it is possible for this case, what about the PC version or any console?

Comment: You can on a iPhone and iPad.

Comment: doesn't really help me, but maybe some other guy who is looking for similar info. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately no, as your progress is saved on phone

Comment: Any source for this information? Do you know if later versions allow this, or when playing on PC?

Comment: @StampedeXV The later version (Magic Duels) definitely doesn't, as there's no cross account sync.